# Truncate questions in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I remove a row by using Truncate in SQL instead of delete by using WHERE condition?
Truncate only use to remove the table or row? if can remove the row by truncate, let me know anyone

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Only `DELETE` statements can have a `WHERE` condition on them, `TRUNCATE` removes all rows.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql) :

> Removes all rows from a table or specified partitions of a table,
>   without logging the individual row deletions. TRUNCATE TABLE is
>   similar to the DELETE statement with no WHERE clause; however,
>   TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log
>   resources.

Comment: For those that don't bother to view the documentation link, partition-level truncate is only available in SQL 2016. Only a full table truncate is available in SQL 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can only remove a single row with truncate if that row is the only one in the table.

Comment: You can only remove a single row with truncate if that row is the only one in the table. Can I have the query for this?

Comment: There is no query for that, Jeni.  "Truncate table" is a DDL, it will always remove all the rows in that table, without possibility of rollback.  I'm afraid you didn't understand what I said, perhaps I shouldn't have said it.  Better read the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

[`Truncate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql) is not like [`delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql).
You can't use truncate to delete specific rows.
In fact, the statement is `truncate table` - you can't truncate anything other then a full table.

Truncate will remove all rows from the table, and is only allowed if the table is not referenced by foreign keys, is not used as the basis of an indexed view, and is not published by transactional replication or merge replication.

Also, `truncate table` can't be executed inside a transaction.

`Truncate table` will also reset the identity column of the table (if one exists).